# Deleted permissions still shown at apk installation

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

Recently i have used `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in my app. At apk installation my phone showed me that my app needs to use Phone calls permission (inherently).

Then i removed that permission (deleted `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` line in manifest) and generated a new apk. While installing the new apk, phone still shows that my app needs Phone calls permission. I cleaned the project but the result is same.

How can these permissions be update?

Comment: Did you do a full uninstall on your phone?  If not, it generally keeps old permissions (Android adds new permissions but doesn't remove old permissions).

Comment: I uninstalled the app with normal uninstallation. What should i do for _full_ uninstallation?

Comment: If you did it via uninstall on the phone, that's probably enough.  If you do it from the command line there's an uninstall mode that keeps private files around (so you don't need to redownload them).  You'd want to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, I did via uninstall on the phone and then installed the new apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike with the java source files, changing the Manifest file alone tends not to trigger a true rebuild.  Anytime you change one of your xml files, clean the project before re-deploying it.